# Multiple Authentication Middlewares ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am relatively new to the concept of middlewares. I am aware that a middleware calls the next middleware when it completes.

I am trying to authenticate a request using either Google or my Identity Server. The user can login on my mobile app with google or a local account. However, I can't figure out how to use both authentication middlewares. If I pass the id_token for google, it passes on the first middleware (`UseJwtBearerAuthentication`) but fails on the second one (`UseIdentityServerAuthentication`). How can I make it so that it doesn't throw error when it actually passes on at least 1 authentication middleware? For example, if it passes on the first middleware, the second middleware is ignored?

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
{
    Authority = "https://accounts.google.com",
    Audience = "secret.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = "accounts.google.com"
    },
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false
});

app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:1000/",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

    ScopeName = "MyApp.Api"
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, when an authentication middleware is failed(i don't mean throwing exception), this doesn't affect another successful authentication middleware. Probably your second middleware throws an exception(not a validation failure). First check error message and try to resolve it. If you can't, use `AuthenticationFailed` event to handle error. In this case your code should be something like below:

```
 app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
 {
     // ...
     Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
     {
          OnAuthenticationFailed = async (context) =>
          {
              if (context.Exception is your exception)
              {
                   context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
              }
          }
     }
 });
```

**However**, for your scenerio i wouldn't choose your way. I would use only identity server endpoint. For signing with google you can configure identity server like below:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
            AutomaticChallenge = false
        });

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
            SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            ClientId = "",
            ClientSecret = ""
        });

        app.UseIdentityServer();
```

**Edit**

It seems `AuthenticationFailed` event couldn't be used for `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation`. I am not sure but if you will use identity server for only jwt token, you can use `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` for validation.

Comment: Will try solution 2 when I got home and mark this as the answer after that. Thank you for your reply.